# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter dropping millis when they're zero?

Tags: java, datetime, console, formatting, datetimeformatter

This seems weird. Java 8 is formatting the output differently depending on whether the millis is zero. How do you force Java 8 (1.8.0_20) to always spit out the millis regardless of if they're zero or not?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TemporalAccessor zeroedMillis = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse("2015-07-14T20:50:00.000Z");
    TemporalAccessor hasMillis = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse("2015-07-14T20:50:00.333Z");
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(zeroedMillis));
    System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(hasMillis));
}

2015-07-14T20:50:00Z
2015-07-14T20:50:00.333Z
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't use `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, basically :)

If you follow the documentation for that, you end up in the docs of `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` which has:

> This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing the ISO-8601 extended local time format. The format consists of:
>
> - Two digits for the hour-of-day. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the minute-of-hour. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the second-of-minute is not available then the format is complete.
> - A colon
> - Two digits for the second-of-minute. This is pre-padded by zero to ensure two digits.
> - If the nano-of-second is zero or not available then the format is complete.
> - A decimal point
> - One to nine digits for the nano-of-second. As many digits will be output as required.

If you always want exactly 3 digits, I suspect you want [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-) with a pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately, that pattern fails to parse: "could not be parsed at index 23". Searches seem to indicate some sort of bug related to fractional (milli) parsing.

Comment: @Chris: Will have a look when I've finished tea :)

Comment: @ChrisKessel: Hmm... it works for me...that's very odd.

Comment: I'm trying this, what's your code look like? DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse("2016-02-03T10:40:31.457Z");  Error: Text '2016-02-03T10:40:31.457Z' could not be parsed at index 23

Comment: @ChrisKessel: Ah, so it's parsing the *value* that's the problem. From your previous comment I thought you meant the *pattern* failed to parse, i.e. that `ofPattern` failed. Will look into that.

Comment: @ChrisKessel: Fixed it - it needs an X instead of a Z at the end. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Strange, the same format with the Z worked in joda, so I figured it'd work in java time. I guess their interpretations of the codes are different?

Comment: @Chris: Yup, every API has its own pattern oddities :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102524/discussion-between-chris-kessel-and-jon-skeet).