# Parse non ISO 8601 to ISO_INSTANT

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, instant

I'm trying parse this String `2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00` and this `Wed May 20 14:27:00 CEST 2020` to a ISO_INSTANT, but always return this exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00' could not be parsed at index 10
```

My code is:

```
protected Instant parseDateTime(String fechaHora) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
        TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(fechaHora);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Instant result = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
        return result; }
```

How can I convert this types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS xxx" )
)
.toInstant()
```

## Fixing your code

Your code is flawed in a few ways.

Use of `TemporalAccessor` is unnecessary and inappropriate here. To quote [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html):

> This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be
>      widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create
>      and pass around instances of concrete types

`LocalDateTime` is not appropriate here as it strips away vital information, the time zone or offset-from-UTC.

You specified a formatter whose formatting pattern does not match your inputs.

## Solution

Manipulate your input string to comply with standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Replace the SPACE between date and time with `T`. Delete SPACE between time and offset.

```
String input = "2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00" ;
String[] strings = input.split( " " ) ;
String modifiedInput = strings[0] + "T" + strings[1] + strings[2] ;
```

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime`, a date with time-of-day in the context of an offset-from-UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( modifiedInput ) ;
```

Or, define a formatting pattern to match your input string. Use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

The predefined formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` that you tried to use does not match your input. Your input does not comply with the ISO 8601 standard used by that formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS xxx" ) ;
String input = "2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/RhyYzr).

> odt.toString(): 2020-05-20T14:27:00.943Z

If you need to return an `Instant`, call `toInstant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

To see that same moment in the context of a time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

The `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` objects represent the same moment, same point on the timeline.

Comment: Thanks for explanation,  lot of useful informations.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you very much, this works perfect. I'll try to change the origin of data to meet ISO 8601 like you suggest.
Best regards.

Comment: @BasilBourque All work perfect with this code:

"DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS xxx" ) ;
String input = "2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;"

Except when arrive a date like "2020-05-20 14:27:00.000000000 +00:00" or "2020-05-20 14:27:00.000000001 +00:00". 

If miliseconds are "00000000" the result of conversion is like "2020-05-20T14:27:00Z".

How can i format it to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"?

Comment: @rolling As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString()), the default formatter suppresses unnecessary zeros in the fractional second to print digits in groups of three. If you want another format, use another `DateTimeFormatter`, perhaps using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. Those classes have been covered many many times, search to learn more. Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35184481/642706).

Comment: @rolling And, understand that the result of parsing a string into a date-time object is a date-time object, not a `String`, not text. Date-time objects like `OffsetDateTime` do not have a “format”.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your exception is the different format between your String `2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00` and `ISO_INSTANT` ; from [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT) `ISO_INSTANT` accepts strings like `2011-12-03T10:15:30Z` and this is not your case. A possible solution to this problem is use a custom `DateTimeFormatter` like below:

```
String fechaHora = "2020-05-20 14:27:00.943000000 +00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS ZZZZZ");
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(fechaHora);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.from(temporalAccessor);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant result = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
System.out.println(result); //<-- it will print 2020-05-20T12:27:00.943Z
```

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is not appropriate here as it strips away vital information, the time zone of offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Use of `TemporalAccessor` is unnecessary and inappropriate here. To quote [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html): This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create and pass around instances of concrete types

Comment: @BasilBourque Hello, I just copied code from the OP, this is the reason why I'm using it.

Comment: Hi, thanks but i've same exception with another format. java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed May 20 14:27:00 CEST 2020' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: @BasilBourque In this case could be acceptable as an answer leave just the definition of the custom formatter and delete the OP code lines ?

Comment: @rolling You need to define a formatting pattern for each kind of string input. That other format of yours has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to find examples. Or simply read the `DateTimeFormatter` Javadoc and experiment. Furthermore, that other format of yours is a very poor choice for exchanging date-time values as text. I suggest you educate the publisher of your data about the ISO 8601 standard.