# Java 8 convert Date String into Date with timezone

Tags: java, date, java-8

I have received a string in format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"

e.g. "2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00"

I want to convert it into "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ"

e.g "2020-06-01T11:04:02.000+0200"

**I don't know the time zone actually. It should take from that last part of string as it is.**

I have tried but it is taking my local time and time zone when I convert string to date(i.e IST).

```
        SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        //sd1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
        Date dt = sd1.parse("2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00");
        SimpleDateFormat sd2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ");
        System.out.println(sd2.format(dt));
```

Output:

```
2020-06-01T14:34:02:000+0530
```

*Only date is right, time and timezone has changed.*

I know I am doing it wrong, it will be really helpful if someone can tell me how can I do this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat parse loses timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone)

Comment: Why are you using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? Java 8 has the `java.time` with much improved alternatives.

Comment: @rph no that question did not help me

Comment: @fjsventura I haven't worked much in java. Can you please elaborate how that can help me in this conversion.

Comment: [1] The _"+02:00"_ within your call to `sd1.parse("2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00")` is incorrect, but is ignored rather than treated as invalid. The Javadoc for `parse()` states _"The method **may not use the entire text** of the given string"_, and a time zone value is meaningless for a `Date`. Verify this by changing it some other value (such as _"+09:00"_) and see that it has no effect. [2] Please update your question to clarify the **exact** output you want/expect for some sample input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

## `OffsetDateTime`

You said:

> I have received a string in format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
>
> e.g. "2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00"

No need to define a formatting pattern. Your input complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

These standard formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings.

Your input should be parsed as a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
String input = "2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00

### Offset-from-UTC versus time zone

You said:

> I don't know the time zone actually.

That `+02:00` on the end is not a time zone. That text represents a mere offset-from-UTC. An offset is just a number of hours-minutes-seconds, positive or negative. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone has a name in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `Europe/Brussels` or `Africa/Cairo`.

You can adjust from a mere offset to a specific time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-06-01T14:34:02+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

You said:

> It should take from that last part of string as it is.

I am not sure what you meant by that. If you parse your input as an `OffsetDateTime`, that object knows its offset, accessible as a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
ZoneOffset offset = odt.getOffset() ;
```

See the code shown in this Answer [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/TysMHU).

> offset.toString(): +02:00

### Formatting strings

You said:

> I want to convert it into "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ"
>
> e.g "2020-06-01T11:04:02.000+0200"

Not sure what you mean here. Do you mean to force the display of milliseconds even if the value is zero? Firstly, you should know that *java.time* objects have a resolution of nanoseconds for up to nine decimal digits, much finer that the milliseconds shown in 3 digits of a decimal fraction. Secondly, forcing display of fractional second has been covered on Stack Overflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35184481/642706). Always **search Stack Overflow** before posting.

Or do you mean displaying the offset without a COLON character as a delimiter between minutes and seconds?

- I advise against this. While dropping the COLON is technically allowed by the ISO 8601 standard, I have seen more than one software library or system fail to handle an offset without that delimiter. Ditto for using an offset of hours without the minutes. I advise always using the hours, the minutes, and the delimiter.
- If you insist, use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with a formatting pattern. Study the Javadoc, keeping mind that the formatting codes are (a) case-sensitive, and (b) sensitive to repeating the character 0, 1, or more times. Here we use `xx` to get the hours and minutes of an offset without the COLON character delimiting. (Again, I do not recommend that format.)

Code shown in that [same IdeOne.com page](https://ideone.com/TysMHU).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxx" ) ;     
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

> output: 2020-06-01T11:04:02.000+0200

### `Date::toString` injects time zone

You said:

> I have tried but it is taking my local time and time zone when I convert string to date(i.e IST).

The `java.util.Date::toString` method tells a lie. While well-intentioned, that method unfortunately applies the JVM’s current default time zone to the `Date` value as it generates the text. The `Date` class actually represents a moment in UTC. This is one of many reasons to *never use `Date`*. That class nowadays is replaced by `java.time.Instant`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Yeah, actually I was confused between time zone and zone offset, ZoneOffset did the work. thank you so much for your answer and clarification.

Answer (score 5):

The first suggestion I would make to you is to switch from using the Date object to LocalDateTime (java 8+)

Using the new API would work in this way

```
String YOUR_DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YOUR_DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input_date, formatter);

//Then you can set your timezone in this way - remember to replace the values with the proper timezone you want. 



ZonedDateTime zonedUTC = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

ZonedDateTime zonedIST = zonedUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

let me know if that works for you

Comment: It is giving me **2020-06-01T11:04:02**  output and I want that +0200 (see example in question), actually date-time can came from various timezones, is there any way we can identify that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use some regex or string parsing to extract the timezone you need?

Comment: Switching to java.time is a very good idea. `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use, you are losing the offset information from the stirng. `ZonedDateTime` will work, but `OffsetDateTime` is a still better fit.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate the comment and picking up on @Daniel Vilas-Boas answer, you should go for Java8 and I think what you want is something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String YOUR_DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
    String YOUR_NEW_DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YOUR_DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
    DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(YOUR_NEW_DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-06-01T11:04:02+02:00", formatter);

    ZoneId from = ZoneId.from(zonedDateTime);
    System.out.println(from);

    ZonedDateTime zonedIST = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

    System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(newFormatter));
    System.out.println(zonedIST.format(newFormatter));
}
```

The `prints` should print:

```
2020-06-01T11:04:02:000+0000
2020-06-01T16:34:02:000+0530
```

**EDIT**

Included `ZoneId` to allow handling different timezones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just one more thing. Is there any way form that we can identify the time zone my date have? like in above example it's +02:00, I want that +02:00 in output but in next input it might be +05:30 or something else how can we solve that. hope you understand what I want to say.

Comment: I've updated my code to include what you requested. The `from` will return the ZoneId (in this case just `+02:00`) and you can use it to handle different zones

Comment: Thank you for your help, because I did not knew the actual time zone, with ZoneOffset I extracted that offset from string itself.